# Efficient way of reading data from inventory

Tags: ansible

What's the best way to read host variables from inventory file provided the script will not access the host? I want to create some virtual machines first before installing our test application in those machines. So, I want to keep the parameters required to create virtual machine in same inventory file so that I can use the same file to create virtual machines and to install our test product on those machines. The inventory will look like the following:

```
[testmachines1]
host1 vm=vmname1 description=vm1description
host2 vm=vmname2 description=vm2description

[testmachines2]
host3 vm=vmname3 description=vm3description
host4 vm=vmname4 description=vm4description
```

Script that will create the virtual machines will not access the hosts rather will read the parameters and create virtual machines accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to do this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="VM={{ hostvars[item].vm }}, Desc={{ hostvars[item]. description }}"
      when: hostvars[item].vm is defined
      with_inventory_hostnames: all
```